# Extracting value from xml data in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, extract

I need help with extracting data corresponding to a tag from the xml data stored in one of my table column. Below is a sample xml data in my table and I need to extract the value corresponding to the tag 'REQUESTTYPE'.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE VXIN SYSTEM "VXInData.dtd">
<VXIN>
<REQUESTS>
<REQUEST>
<REQUESTTYPE>ADD</REQUESTTYPE>
<REQUESTNUMBER>12345</REQUESTNUMBER>
<ID>1234567</ID>
<ACCESSLIST>
<ACCESS>
<ACCESSLEVEL>
<AID>123789</AID>
</ACCESSLEVEL>
<PERSONNEL>
<REQUESTEDFOR>
<UID>13579</UID>
<FIRSTNAME>MOBY</FIRSTNAME>
</REQUESTEDFOR>
</PERSONNEL>
</ACCESS>
</ACCESSLIST>
</REQUEST>
</REQUESTS>
</VXIN>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: PLEASE show what your expected output is, table schema definition also.

Comment: I think that's quite well specified.

Comment: I am looking for a query that returns 'ADD' for the above xml. My table has above xml column and few other date attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EXTRACTVALUE function is deprecated. It is still supported for backward compatibility. However, Oracle recommends that you use the XMLTABLE function, or the XMLCAST and XMLQUERY functions instead. See XMLTABLE, XMLCAST, and XMLQUERY for more information, see [EXTRACTVALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions069.htm#SQLRF06173)

Function `xmltable` works fine, you can also use [XMLQUERY](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions265.htm#SQLRF06209):

```
SELECT XMLQUERY('/VXIN/REQUESTS/REQUEST/REQUESTTYPE/text()' 
   PASSING XMLTYPE('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<VXIN>
<REQUESTS>
<REQUEST>
<REQUESTTYPE>ADD</REQUESTTYPE>
<REQUESTNUMBER>12345</REQUESTNUMBER>
<ID>1234567</ID>
<ACCESSLIST>
<ACCESS>
<ACCESSLEVEL>
<AID>123789</AID>
</ACCESSLEVEL>
<PERSONNEL>
<REQUESTEDFOR>
<UID>13579</UID>
<FIRSTNAME>MOBY</FIRSTNAME>
</REQUESTEDFOR>
</PERSONNEL>
</ACCESS>
</ACCESSLIST>
</REQUEST>
</REQUESTS>
</VXIN>') RETURNING CONTENT) AS REQUESTTYPE
FROM dual;
```

However, in case you like to extract more than just one value XMLTABLE() should be better.

Comment: Thanks Wernfried, the above solution worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it:

```
declare
   l_xml         xmltype;
   l_requesttype varchar2(30);
begin
   l_xml := xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<VXIN>
<REQUESTS>
<REQUEST>
<REQUESTTYPE>ADD</REQUESTTYPE>
<REQUESTNUMBER>12345</REQUESTNUMBER>
<ID>1234567</ID>
<ACCESSLIST>
<ACCESS>
<ACCESSLEVEL>
<AID>123789</AID>
</ACCESSLEVEL>
<PERSONNEL>
<REQUESTEDFOR>
<UID>13579</UID>
<FIRSTNAME>MOBY</FIRSTNAME>
</REQUESTEDFOR>
</PERSONNEL>
</ACCESS>
</ACCESSLIST>
</REQUEST>
</REQUESTS>
</VXIN>');

   select x.*
     into l_requesttype
     from xmltable('/VXIN/REQUESTS/REQUEST' passing l_xml columns requesttype varchar2(30) path 'REQUESTTYPE') x;

   dbms_output.put_line(l_requesttype);
end;
```

As you can see I've removed the reference to the DTD since the database can not access it. 
To run this code with the DTD reference you can tell the parser not to go look for it.

```
declare
   l_xml         xmltype;
   l_requesttype varchar2(30);
begin

   execute immediate 'alter session set events =''31156 trace name context forever, level 2''';

   l_xml := xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE VXIN SYSTEM "VXInData.dtd">
<VXIN>
<REQUESTS>
<REQUEST>
<REQUESTTYPE>ADD</REQUESTTYPE>
<REQUESTNUMBER>12345</REQUESTNUMBER>
<ID>1234567</ID>
<ACCESSLIST>
<ACCESS>
<ACCESSLEVEL>
<AID>123789</AID>
</ACCESSLEVEL>
<PERSONNEL>
<REQUESTEDFOR>
<UID>13579</UID>
<FIRSTNAME>MOBY</FIRSTNAME>
</REQUESTEDFOR>
</PERSONNEL>
</ACCESS>
</ACCESSLIST>
</REQUEST>
</REQUESTS>
</VXIN>');

   select x.*
     into l_requesttype
     from xmltable('/VXIN/REQUESTS/REQUEST' passing l_xml columns requesttype varchar2(30) path
                   'REQUESTTYPE') x;

   dbms_output.put_line(l_requesttype);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Rene, the above block works! Is there a single line query that i could use to directly read xml data from table and get the desired output. The reason I am asking is because i will have to do this operation for multiple records in the table whichever satisfies my where clause.

Comment: Simply replace `xmltype()`, resp. `l_xml` with your column name.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solution posted by Wernfried, I tuned the query a bit to read the values from my table. Below is my final query:

```
select XMLQUERY('/VXIN/REQUESTS/REQUEST/REQUESTTYPE/text()' passing xmltype(XML_DATA) RETURNING CONTENT) AS REQUESTTYPE from table;
```

Comment: What is the data type of column `XML_DATA`? In case of `XMLTYPE` you don't have to make `xmltype(XML_DATA)`, you can just use `XML_DATA`. `xmltype(XML_DATA)` would be required if datatype is VARCHAR2 or CLOB

Comment: Yes @Wernfried Domscheit, the XML_DATA in my table is of CLOB datatype